# Can non Matter thread end devices join a Matter network through a bridge

Tags: c, wireless, matter-iot-standard

Everything is in the title. I have some Thread end devices with to small memory to include Matter application layer. So I was wondering if it's possible to add this Matter application layer on a bridge or Open Thread Border Router side as it is possible for ZigBee.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes non Matter thread end devices can join a Matter network through a bridge.
- A Bridge serves to allow the use of non-Matter IoT devices (e.g. devices on a Zigbee or Z-Wave network, or any other non-Matter connectivity technology) in a Matter Fabric, with the goal to enable the consumer to keep using these non-Matter devices together with their Matter devices.
- You can refer to the following [matter spec document](https://csa-iot.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/22-27349-001_Matter-1.0-Core-Specification.pdf) to get an idea of how to implement.